# Remove array of objects from array of objects with Jquery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

Might be duplicate, but I couldn't find it.
So I have two arrays of objects:

```
var a = [{id: '1', name: 'bob'}, {id: '2', name: 'bill'}]
$scope.b = [{id: '4', name: 'jack'}, {id: '2', name: 'bill'}, {id: '1', name: 'bob'}, {id: '3', name: 'john'}]
```

I want to remove all the a elements from b. 
I have tried:

```
$scope.b = $scope.b.filter(function(item){
   return a.indexOf(item) === -1;
});
```

unfortunately, for some reason, the index is always -1, so nothing gets deleted.
with some console.log-s

```
console.log(item);
console.log(a);
console.log(a.indexOf(item));
```

, this is how the data looks like:

```
Resource {id: 4, name: "jack"}
[Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, $promise: Promise, $resolved: true]
-1
```

Comment: `indexOf` is looking for a reference to the same object - they're not. Do you want to delete by `id`? or perhaps only when `id` and `name` match?

Comment: by id would be fine (some text to fill in the required length of this input)

Comment: Then your answer is already below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
// get all id's from a
var a = [{id: '1', name: 'bob'}, {id: '2', name: 'bill'}].map(function (el) {
    return el.id;
});

// search item.id in array with id's
$scope.b = $scope.b.filter(function(item){
   return a.indexOf(item.id) === -1;
});
```

Comment: @phari - it actually works, am I doing something so wrong that it went right? :))  Alexander - you're the king of everything! :)) thanks a lot!

Comment: @phari - well, it is not really "a", it is users, and I get all the users from the db. I have changed the above code a bit into: userIds = users.map(...); and return userIds.indexOf(item.id) === -1;